# How get all data from a pouchDB-database into a html-table using bootstrap and vue?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, pouchdb

In a vue-component I am using the node module of pouchDB(7.0.0) to save data from a html input form. Testing in the browser, the data will saving in IndexedDB. Then I will get all data from that pouch-database and showing it in a bootstrap/html-table.
Unfortunately, I've got some problems with the use of asynchronous functions of pouchDB and the work with promises or callbacks.
I think, i have to return the result to work with that data, but i read that's impossible with async functions. So how can I get the data from the pouchDB database and showing it to the table?

```
  <template>
  <div>
  <form method="post">
    <button type="button" @click="addPost" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <label>Maker:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="maker" v-model="maker">
      </div>
      <b-table :items="makers"></b-table>
    </div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <br>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PouchDB from "pouchdb";
const db = new PouchDB('makersDB')
const makers = getData()
console.log(food)

function getData() {
  db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true
  }).then(function (result) {

//parsing result-data to json object, get the right format btable 
    var list = []
    console.log(result.rows[1].doc.maker)
    for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      var obj = {
        maker: result.rows[i].doc.maker
      }
      list.push(obj)
    }
// that return statement won't work
    return list

  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
}

//vue instance
export default {
  name: 'CompName',
  data: function () {
    return {
        makers: makers,
        maker: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
     addPost () {
      db.put({
        _id: 'mew',
        maker: this.maker
      }).then(function (response) {
        // handle response
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });

    }
  }

}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I notice in your getData function you did not return the Promise from allDocs - perhaps a typo? Anyway - try "return allDocs({" etc as this may help solve the problem.

Comment: I changed to callbacks instead of promises and that worked for me. Also setting a list variable in the data function and add the items in the callback to it. The rest is bootstrap doing. Unfortunately the async function gets all data in different orders, so you have to sorting it.